# What is the ip address used to communicate 2 docker containers?

Tags: docker, http, networking

I have 2 docker containers and they are connected using docker network. I run the following command twice.

```
docker network connect [network id] [container id]
```

The first container need to communicate with the second container by HTTP.

I set the ip to 172.17.0.1, but look like the ip is wrong.

I believe this is a common question for those experience docker users.

Can anyone help me?

Regards,
Jimmy

Comment: use docker-compose.yml file

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case that the container didn't connect to the network. For checking that you can inspect the network to which the containers are connected so that they can communicate. 
Use the command `docker network inspect network_name`

If the network is default network bridge you can see the following o/p before the container are attached to it:

```
[
   {
       "Name": "bridge",
       "Id": "f7ab26d71dbd6f557852c7156ae0574bbf62c42f539b50c8ebde0f728a253b6f",
       "Scope": "local",
       "Driver": "bridge",
       "IPAM": {
           "Driver": "default",
           "Config": [
               {
                   "Subnet": "172.17.0.1/16",
                   "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
               }
           ]
       },
       "Containers": {},
       "Options": {
           "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
           "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
           "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
           "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
           "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
           "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "9001"
       },
       "Labels": {}
   }
]
```

And once two containers are attached then the o/p will be as shown below:

```
{[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "f7ab26d71dbd6f557852c7156ae0574bbf62c42f539b50c8ebde0f728a253b6f",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.1/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Containers": {
            "3386a527aa08b37ea9232cbcace2d2458d49f44bb05a6b775fba7ddd40d8f92c": {
                "EndpointID": "647c12443e91faf0fd508b6edfe59c30b642abb60dfab890b4bdccee38750bc1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "94447ca479852d29aeddca75c28f7104df3c3196d7b6d83061879e339946805c": {
                "EndpointID": "b047d090f446ac49747d3c37d63e4307be745876db7f0ceef7b311cbba615f48",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "9001"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

As you can see there is the ip-addresses of the two containers in the o/p.

Now you can attach to a container and try to ping the other container to see that they can communicate.

You can follow [docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#the-default-bridge-network) for complete details

Comment: I run docker exec -it ping [container name], looks okay. But how I know I can communicate with the port? for eg: http:172.21.0.2:1234

Comment: Try to ping one of the containers from other. If it works that means both can communicate. In my understanding that’s how we test connectivity on the network.

Comment: No problem ping. I get

PING rinkeby (172.21.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.21.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.103 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.2: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.084 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.2: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.071 ms

Comment: I want to communicate with 172.21.0.2:9007 from another docker... is that possible?

Comment: if two systems are connected to a network and discovery is enabled then they can discover each other and communicate. Same thing in case of docker containers on a  same network. That's what Ping o/p also shows.

Comment: or as mentioned in the question comment you can use docker-compose also which is used if you have multiple containers on the same host. Docker-compose will start all the containers and put them in a network.

Comment: Perhaps can communicate with 172.21.0.2 but cannot communicate with 9007